# Error closing forms on C#

Tags: c#

I am making a simple test program but I have a problem when I close the final form clicking on the Close buttom of the form (the normal buttom on the upper right of the window, not a buttom made by myself).

This is the code, the comments are just to identify the persons:

```
   public partial class Preguntas : Form
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int[] score = { 
        /*Vir*/    0,
        /*Eva*/    0,
        /*Pedro*/  0 };

    string[] questions = new string[] {
        /*Vir*/    "¿Qué prefiero ver?","2","3","4","5",
        /*Eva*/    "a","2","3","4","5",
        /*Pedro*/  "1","2","3","4","5",
    };

    string[] opt1 = new string[] { 
        /*Vir*/    "Películas de serie B","2","3","4","5",
        /*Eva*/    "1","2","3","4","5",
        /*Pedro*/  "1","2","3","4","5",
    };

    string[] opt2 = new string[] { 
        /*Vir*/    "Series","2","3","4","5",
        /*Eva*/    "1","2","3","4","5",
        /*Pedro*/  "1","2","3","4","5",
    };

    string[] opt3 = new string[] { 
        /*Vir*/    "Películas romanticas","2","3","4","5",
        /*Eva*/    "1","2","3","4","5",
        /*Pedro*/  "1","2","3","4","5",
    };

    string[] opt4 = new string[] { 
        /*Vir*/    "Películas de acción","2","3","4","5",
        /*Eva*/    "1","2","3","4","5",
        /*Pedro*/  "1","2","3","4","5",
    };

    int[] correctAnswer = { 
        /*Vir*/    1,1,1,1,1,
        /*Eva*/    1,1,1,1,1,
        /*Pedro*/  1,1,1,1,1
    };


    public Preguntas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RefreshTest();
    }

    public void FinishTest()
    {
        i = 0;  // I dont know why i have to put this but if not
        j = 0;  //  a axception when close the program occurs.
        Resultado f2 = new Resultado(score);
        this.Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    public void RefreshTest()
    {
        if (i == 15) FinishTest();

        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
        pictureBox2.Image = imageList2.Images[j];

        label1.Text = opt1[i];
        label2.Text = opt2[i];
        label3.Text = opt3[i];
        label4.Text = opt4[i];
        label5.Text = questions[i];

    }

    public void Correction(int answer)
    {
        if(correctAnswer[i] == answer)
        {
            score[j] += 1;
        }

        if (++i % 5 == 0) j++;

        RefreshTest();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Correction(1);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Correction(2);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Correction(3);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Correction(4);
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '15' is not valid for 'index'.

It occurs on the RefreshTest on this line:
    `pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];`

I suppose that the program when I click the close butom finish the RefreshTest because is in the memory and in the end runs everything it finds on that, but I don´t know how to avoid it.

Comment: Your collection of images doesn't have 15 images, so it hits the OutOfRangeException. Even though you close your form, the RefreshTest() still completes before it shuts down. You call the FinishTest() method without breaking from the code, so once FinishTest() completes, the code then finishes the rest of your RefreshTest() method. Because you are using global variables, you are having to set the i and j variables to 0. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Please add all your variables like I and J they are never defined. It is a better practice to explain what you variable are instead of just letters. Like ImageCounter instead of i.

Comment: use the debugger.. and show a shorted version of the actual issues and or problem.. we do not have time to debug your code for you.. this is part of your job as a developer to do that first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

This is because it can not find the element in you collection of images you are looking for.
You have to make sure the image you assign exists before you assign it.
In this care it is set top 15 which is not in your collection.

```
If(imageList1.Images.Count >= 15)
{
   pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
}
```

If the method runs when you close the program you are either closing the program at the wrong time or you have to let the method know that you are closing so it can skip the code. You could do that with a flag on the on closing event.

Answer (score -1):

You can just wrap your code in an IF-ELSE statement instead of your sole IF statement as follows:

```
public void RefreshTest()
    {
       if(i==15) 
       { 
            FinishTest(); 
       }
       else
       {

            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
            pictureBox2.Image = imageList2.Images[j];

            label1.Text = opt1[i];
            label2.Text = opt2[i];
            label3.Text = opt3[i];
            label4.Text = opt4[i];
            label5.Text = questions[i];

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not correct it is only doing a different function when it equals to 15 but it has to do the rest no matter what according to the code posted.

Comment: That's the problem. It shouldn't do the other bit of code when it equals 15, which is why it won't close without the error. The IF-ELSE will fix that. Even better would be to use variables instead of hard-coding 15 in.